# Black --exclude argument not excluding desired file(s)

Tags: regex, python-black

Let's say I have the following python file `exclude_from_black.py` in the root of my project:

```
print('I want single quotes')
```

I'm trying to exclude this file from black reformatting but none of the following commands seem to work:

```
black --exclude="exclude_from_black.py"
black --exclude="exclude_from_black\.py"
black --exclude="exclude\_from\_black\.py"
```

According to the [Documentation](https://github.com/psf/black#command-line-options) the `exclude` argument takes a regex. What am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Well, try `r"exclude_from_black\.py"`, but the first should also work. It seems the issue is not with the regex

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just tried these examples on `black==20.8b1` and everything works as expected:

```
black --check --verbose --exclude="exclude_from_black.py" .
# exclude_from_black.py ignored: matches the --exclude regular expression

black --check --verbose --exclude="exclude_from_black\.py" .
# exclude_from_black.py ignored: matches the --exclude regular expression
```

Comment: Really should use `--exclude="exclude_from_black\.py"` since it is a regex.

Answer (score 11):

I think you should omit the space after `--exclude` and wrap the regex in `/…/`.

Try `black --exclude '/exclude_from_black\.py/'`

Also, for debugging, `-v` should give some info about which files were excluded.